# Shuffle YouTube playlist with Android and Chromecast

Tags: youtube, chromecast

I'm using a Chromecast, controlled by the YouTube app on a Nexus 7 running Android 4.4. I can select a playlist and it will add all of the videos to my TV Queue, but I can find no option to play in shuffle mode or to randomize the video order.

Am I missing something, or is there a reason that this feature does not exist?

Comment: The feature possibly doesn't exist only on playlists with over 200 songs.